# CSS header - body - footer print on separate pages

Tags: html, css, printing, report

I'm trying to make an HTML report that, when printed, will have a custom header on each page with body content in the form of a table. Footer is optional.

After looking around, I have gotten the header and footer work fine by using

```
@media print{
    div.divFooter {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    div.divHeader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    /* Fix overflow of headers and content */
    body {
        margin-top: 185px;
    }   
}
```

but the body only works on the first page. For every other page, the body content continues and runs into the header on all the following pages. What I need is for the body to page break at a certain margin (let's say 50px from the bottom of the page for example) and then begin again after a certain margin (like 185px from the top of the page) so it is formatted the same on every printed page.

I've tried using the @page margins but those effect the header and footer as well so it ends up running into the same issue.

The content is always a header, a table, and a footer. Is there any reliable way to print that in the way I have described?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for an answer to this question, I ended up manually generating page breaks in the html string server-side every x number of lines.

In a nutshell:

```
// this string inserts a page break in html
private const string PAGE_BREAK = "<p style=\"page-break-after: always;\">&nbsp;</p><p style=\"page-break-before: always;\">&nbsp;</p>";

if (lineCount % x == 0){
   htmlString.insert("</table>"); // close the table, otherwise the page break does nothing
   htmlString.insert(PAGE_BREAK);
   htmlString.insert("<table class='whatever-you-want-'>");
}
```

Not exact but that's the gist of it.

After looking through numerous articles, blog posts, and stack overflow questions, it looks like what I was trying to accomplish isn't currently possible with just html and CSS. If anybody knows otherwise, I would be glad to hear it.